# How can we connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM by using Airflow to retrieve data?

Tags: airflow, dynamics-crm

I am new to airflow and I am unable find any information regarding this question: how can we connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM using Airflow to retrieve data?

I try to find out any link or Youtube link to retrieve the data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM using Airflow but I could not find anything.

Is there any way?